# Iterating over byte stream - performance vs code style

Tags: c

I want to perform some conversions of pixels in bitmap which is given as byte stream.
Depending on bytes per pixel value the final pixels are different, but the code is almost the same. This is because the byte stream is presented as pointer like `uint8_t*, uint16_t*, uint32_t*` and iterating is done with `bytestream[x]`.

Currently my code looks like:

```
if (bytes per pixel == 1) {
    uint8_t *pixels = (uint8_t *) stream;
    // a lot of code iterating over pixels pointer
} else if (bytes per pixel == 2) {
    uint16_t *pixels = (uint16_t *) stream;
    // exactly the same lot of code iterating over pixels pointer
} else if (bytes per pixel == 4) {
    uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *) stream;
    // exactly the same lot of code iterating over pixels pointer
}
```

Problem is the code style, I don't like that the code is repeated. I can't put that into the separate function, because function require pointer in specific type.
In C++ I believe I could use template, but this is C.

The alternative is casting to specific pointer type per each pixel, so the ifology with repeated code would be smaller, but I believe this could harm the performance.
Something like that:

```
uint8_t *pixels = (uint8_t *) stream;
// a lot of code iterating with `pixel = pixels + i * bytesPerPixel

//finally setting pixels
some loop {
    if (bytes per pixel == 1) {
        // one or two lines
    } else if (bytes per pixel == 2) {
        // one or two lines
    } else if (bytes per pixel == 4) {
        // one or two lines
    }
}
```

This is a lot smaller, but as I said before this could limit the performance, since we are doing this check per every pixel.

Is making such checks per pixel is troublesome on current machines (example ~1GHz ARM cpu)?

Comment: Measure. Since bytes-per-pixel appears unmodified throughout either attempt, I wouldn't be surprised if branch-prediction had its way with the latter, assuming your ARM has a decent PFU.

Comment: The 2nd style won't make any difference on an optimizing compiler (as long as `bytes_per_pixel` visibly doesn't change in the body of the loop, the compiler should hoist the `if-else ladder`, outputting 3 distinct loops).

Comment: Did you measure the performance for both? I would imagine since the bytes per pixel are a compile time constant, the compiler could technically turn this into a jump table and therefore eliminate the branches. Similar to what you could do with an array of function pointers which you would call as `array[bytes_per_pixel]();`.

Comment: If you have the same code repeated verbatim, then you could consider defining a macro for it, and expanding that macro in each place where you want the code.  That has some maintenance advantages in that the physical code is shorter, you cannot accidentally introduce differences between the blocks, and the intent that they be identical is crystal clear.  That won't necessarily provide any *performance* advantage, but it would still be worth considering.